# PSU required wattage

Tags: power-supply, gpu, intel-core-i7

I am planning on buying, when it's released, an i7-9700k with an Asus Z390 Maximus Hero XI and a 1070ti. I currently own a Corsair H100i V2, 2x 8gb Kingston ddr4, 3x thermaltake riing 120mm fans.

The question is if everything will work fine with a Xfx Xtr 650w 80+ gold. I am not overclocking any of the components.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

- The announced TDP of the i7-9700k  is 95W according to [Intel](https://ark.intel.com/products/186604/Intel-Core-i7-9700K-Processor-12M-Cache-up-to-4-90-GHz-) and [Wikichip](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/core_i7/i7-9700k).
- the Asus Z390 Maximus Hero XI is not released yet so there is no concrete data available but a gaming motherboard can easily use up to 450W if overclocked. As you don't want to do that we'll calculate 250W. [Here](https://www.overclock.net/forum/6-intel-motherboards/1638955-z370-z390-vrm-discussion-thread-134.html#post26485705) they overclocked similar MoBos and got a max of 250W.
- As you have not mentioned which GTX 1070 Ti you want, so I just took the ones from [Nvidia](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/products/10series/geforce-gtx-1070-ti/) 180W
- I couldn't find the required wattage for the Corsair H100i V2 but found out it needed two headers as power source á 1.8W = 3.6W
- Again you did not specify the type of RAM but I assumed around 4W per stick = 8W
- 3x fans = 3x 1.8W = 5.4W
- I assume you have one HDD and one SSD á ~ 10W = 20W

All summarised together equals 562W, this means your PSU should not be maxed out but doesn't get bored either.

<sup>If anyone has better links/information please comment and I'll correct my answer.</sup>

Comment: https://ark.intel.com und https://ark.intel.com/de/ are nifty places for specs.

Comment: Well, I've already linked to https://ark.intel.com

Comment: The *motherboard* itself uses only a few dozen watts at most. Under load, most of the power is fed to the processor, with some power lost in voltage conversion at the VRM.

Comment: Naah, I snuck that in there while you weren;t looking.  https://www.asus.com/de/Motherboards/ROG-MAXIMUS-X-HERO/specifications/  und  https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1151/ROG_MAXIMUS_X_HERO/G13247_ROG_MAXIMUS_X_HERO_UM_WEB.pdf  https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/ROG-MAXIMUS-X-HERO/specifications/  could also be handy.

Comment: Ah well, thanks. I did not look if you edited it and just saw there was a link to ark.intel.com. thanks by the way.